# Is there any endpoint to get all custom audiences (facebook API)?

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

i need some help please, 
i can't find any ENDPOINT to get list of all custom audiences

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience

thanks

Comment: If you need all the custom audiences owned by an adaccounts you can use this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/customaudiences/

Comment: you are welcome @startdev let me know if this is what you're looking for or if you need more help

Comment: Thank you , That is what I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you need all the custom audiences owned by an adaccounts you can use the [Ad Account Customaudiences Endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/customaudiences/):

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/customaudiences?fields=id
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Matteo's answer is correct. To add the fields you'll want to include:

https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/act_/customaudiences?fields=id,name,subtype,description,customer_file_source,is_value_based,pixel_id,retention_days